# p5 - how to detect if a sketch is run from the online editor?

Tags: p5.js

The [online p5 editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) can be very useful to create some small piece of code. I have found a need to detect if the current code is being run from the editor, or if it is not.

For this, I use the following function, which basically read the URL to determine if we're on the online editor or not. This works, but it looks and feels a little hacky to me.

```
function onP5Editor() {
  let document_ancestor = document.location.ancestorOrigins;
  if (document_ancestor.length) { // if it's in an iframe{}
    return document_ancestor[0].includes('editor.p5js.org');
  }
  return false;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `const onP5Editor = location.hostname === "editor.p5js.org";` seems simpler. What's the iframe situation you're referring to in the snippet?